# jQuery UI - Modal

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, frontend

I have the following code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#<%=btn1.ClientID %>').bind('click', function (event) {
                $('#modal').dialog({
                    title: 'title',
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        'ok': function () {
                            return true;
                        },
                        'cancel': function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" OnClick="btnClick" Text="click me" />
    <div id="modal" style="visibility: hidden">
        <span>yay!</span>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have an asp:button and on the clientClick the dialog appears.

as you can see I have a asp:button which handles an onclick event on the server-side. However there's also an event that the onclientclick event handler responds to which opens a dialog with two buttons: ok and cancel. However, the dialog disappers and the page executes the OnClick event from the serverside.. Do you have any idea why that is and how I could change that?
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the button submitting a form or the is it on a web form page?

Comment: I didnt understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try manually submitting the form like this:

```
 'ok': function () {
            $('#myform').submit();                        
       },
```

Comment: wow i wasnt aware such a command existed. I've updated the code above. Please do that a look.